# puzzling regex matching weirdness

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var creatingidmatch='website.com'.match(/.idv.tw|.firm.in|.gen.in|.nom.es|.nom.co|.me.uk|.net.ag|.net.br|.net.bz|.net.co|.net.in|.net.nz|.com.ag|.com.br|.com.bz|.com.co|.com.es|.com.mx|.com.tw|.org.ag|.org.tw|.org.in|.org.uk|.org.nz|.org.es|.co.in|.co.uk|.co.nz|.asia|.mobi|.info|.com|.org|.net|.jobs|.biz|.xxx|.ca|.mx|.tv|.ws|.ag|.am|.at|.be|.bz|.cc|.de|.es|.eu|.fm|.fr|.gs|.in|.it|.jp|.ms|.nl|.nu|.se|.tc|.tk|.tw|.vg|.me|.co|.us/gi);
alert(creatingidmatch);
```

This returns

```
sit,.com
```

Where is 'sit' coming from?? (or rather why is it returning the 'sit' part of my string?)

Comment: good point yes i do mean that, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sit` portion is coming from this part of the regular expression: `.it`.  The `.` in a regular expression matches anything (except newline).  Hence the `.` matches `s` and the `it` matches the following `it`.  You need to escape the . if you want it to match a . literal

```
\.it
```

Since every item after a `|` begins with `.` you could simplify the regex a bit by matching that first followed by all of the suffixes.  Here's the updated regex

```
/\.(idv\.tw|firm\.in|gen\.in|nom\.es|nom\.co|me\.uk|net\.ag|net\.br|net\.bz|net\.co|net\.in|net\.nz|com\.ag|com\.br|com\.bz|com\.co|com\.es|com\.mx|com\.tw|org\.ag|org\.tw|org\.in|org\.uk|org\.nz|org\.es|co\.in|co\.uk|co\.nz|asia|mobi|info|com|org|net|jobs|biz|xxx|ca|mx|tv|ws|ag|am|at|be|bz|cc|de|es|eu|fm|fr|gs|in|it|jp|ms|nl|nu|se|tc|tk|tw|vg|me|co|us)/gi;
```

Answer (score 5):

'sit' matches '.it' because '.' matches any character.

Comment: so then each extension must look like \.idv\.tw|\firm\.in|

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
var creatingidmatch = 'website.com'.match(/\.idv\.tw|\.firm\.in| ...
```

Answer (score 1):

the '.' character means to match any non-newline character.

'sit' matches the ".it" condition.

You need to escape all of the '.'s